# How to require a TS file from index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have just created an app from react-express-starter.
Inside I have a "server" folder, which is used by nodejs to create the backend. Inside this folder I have an index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const { Test } = require('./test/index.ts');

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Express server is running on localhost:3001');
  Test.run();
});
```

I need to call a method from a ts file,

server/test/test.ts:

```
export class Test {
    static run(){
        console.log('OK THIS WORKS');
    }
}
```

server/test/index.ts

```
export { Test as test} from './test';
```

Running the server:

```
export { Test as test } from './test';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Another try, adding this to the first line of index.js:

```
import { Test as test } from './test';
```

Result:

```
import { Test as test } from './test';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Now changing the first line in index.js:

```
import * as test from './test';
```

Result:

```
import * as test from './test';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

How do I make things work?

Comment: `import { Test as test } from './test';`

Comment: Hello Ihor, I´ve added what you suggested to the index.js file, and the result is:

C:\Source\react-express-starter-master\server\index.js:2
import { Test as test } from './test';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically we have to compile the typescript files from ts to js. Then only we can import into js files.
So, I would like to recommend all the backend code should be maintained in either javascript or typescript

- For Typescript:
  https://github.com/gokulakannant/express-typescript-mongodb-starter
- For Javascript: https://github.com/GetStream/node-express-mongo-api

You can use any other starter projects like above

Comment: Thanks for sharing your repository! Those transpilations aways gives me a headache.